# Adding contents of a file to a struct

Tags: c++, io

I am supposed to create a program that indexes books in my collection. The struct contains the usual book info: title, author, publisher, etc. However, I am getting no output. One issue is that titles will have spaces.

```
/* Book Inventory assignment 2 by Heath Martens. */

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring> // I had to throw this in in order to get memcpy to work.

using namespace std;

typedef struct book{
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    char publisher[100];
    float price;
    int isbn;
    int pages;
    int copies;
} Book;

Book collection[100];
int currentIndex;


void
indexBook(Book *my_book)
{
    memcpy(&collection[currentIndex], my_book, sizeof(Book));
    currentIndex++;
}

void
readfile(void)
{
    fstream my_stream;
    string line = " ";
    my_stream.open("input.txt");
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
        {
            while (getline(my_stream, line))
            {
                cin >> line >> collection[i].title;
                cin >> line >> collection[i].author;
                cin >> line >> collection[i].publisher;
                cin >> line >> collection[i].price;
                cin >> line >> collection[i].isbn;
                cin >> line >> collection[i].pages;
                cin >> line >> collection[i].copies;
            }
        }

    my_stream.close();

}

void
printCollection(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
    {
        cout << "Title: " << "\t\t" << collection[i].title << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << "\t" << collection[i].author << endl;
        cout << "Publisher: " << "\t" << collection[i].publisher << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << "\t\t" << collection[i].price << endl;
        cout << "ISBN: " << "\t\t" << collection[i].isbn << endl;
        cout << "Pages: " << "\t\t" << collection[i].pages << endl;
        cout << "Copies: " << "\t" << collection[i].copies << endl;
    }
}

void printCollection(void);

int
main(void)
{
    currentIndex = 0;

    Book *my_book = new Book;

    indexBook(my_book);

    readfile();

    printCollection();

    delete my_book;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the txt file I have been given to use.

```
Magician: Apprentice
Raymond E. Feist
Spectra (January 1, 1994)
5.02
0553564943
512
1
Magician: Master
Raymond E. Feist
Spectra (January 1, 1994)
7.99
0553564935
499
1
```

Here is the updated code based on some of the examples provided.

```
    void
    readfile(void)
    {
       fstream my_stream ("input.txt");
       if(!my_stream)
    {
       return;
    }
     string line = " ";
     int i=0;
for (i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++)
    {
        if(!std::getline(my_stream, line))
        {
            break;
        }
        memcpy(collection[currentIndex].title, line.c_str(), std::min(sizeof(collection[currentIndex].title), line.size()));
        memcpy(collection[currentIndex].author, line.c_str(), std::min(sizeof(collection[currentIndex].author), line.size()));
        memcpy(collection[currentIndex].publisher, line.c_str(), std::min(sizeof(collection[currentIndex].publisher), line.size()));
        my_stream >> collection[currentIndex].price;
        my_stream >> collection[currentIndex].isbn;
        my_stream >> collection[currentIndex].pages;
        my_stream >> collection[currentIndex].copies;
        my_stream.ignore();
        if(!my_stream)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

[Error in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iR07.png)

Comment: If you're using C++ you should really consider using `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file struct" for examples of how to read a data file into a structure.  Too many similar questions and answers already.

Comment: Hint: It looks like you only increment `currentIndex` once ever, regardless of how many books are in your txt file.

Comment: Please ask a specific problem and show a minimal example of what you've tried which doesn't work.

Comment: @David his problem is `In this example I am getting no output.`

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `std::fstream my_stream("input.txt");` will open the file; there's no need for a separate call to `my_stream.open()`. And the destructor for `std::fstream` will close the file; there's no need for a separate call to `my_stream.close()`.

Comment: He's getting output. It's just a single book with default constructed values for each data member of the Book type. Which is the only one that actually gets added. There is also a problem with his `readfile` function. He switches between reading from file and stdin.

Comment: hint: also format your data as code for extra win

Answer (score 1):

The main problems are with the readfile function. As stated in the comments, std::fstream can take a string as the first argument, so calling open later is not necessary.  Furthermore, one should check that a file is open before performing operations on it.  std::string does not need to be initialized in order to be used later in this function.  This leads to the following code.

```
fstream my_stream("input.txt");
if(!my_stream) {
    return;
}
string line;
```

readfile's loops do not appear to be constructed correctly.  The outer loop increments over the range of current indices for the collection array, while the inner loop looks as if intended to read the entire file.  If the inner loop was constructed correctly, then the contents of the file would be written to the 0-th Book in collection.  The inner loop begins with testing if reading a line from the file, which is ignored by reading input from std::cin, is successful.

Because the number of "Books" in input.txt is not known, the outer loop seems to be irrelevant to the goal of reading all the "Books" into a different element of collection.  In order to read the whole file, we'll change the loop to check that the file is still readable.

```
while(my_stream) {
```

For reading the strings, we need to read and store the entire line using std::getline (`my_stream >> line;` here will get tripped up by spaces), and memcpy to copy the the contents of the line into the corresponding char array.  Because std::getline may fail, we check for success before using the contents of line.  For example, here's title:

```
// title
if(!std::getline(my_stream, line)) {
    break;
}
memcpy(collection[currentIndex].title, line.c_str(), std::min(sizeof(collection[currentIndex].title), line.size()));
```

For the numbers, we can just read the numbers using operator>> and ignore any extra characters at the end of the line.  Likewise, this operation can fail and is checked as well.  For example, here's price:

```
    my_stream >> collection[currentIndex].price; 
    my_stream.ignore(); 
    if(!my_stream) { 
        break;
    }
```

If all the members of the current Book have been read correctly, then at the end of the loop body, we'll increment the number of Books seen (`++currentIndex;`).  As stated in the comments, explicit closing of my_stream is not necessary in the context of readfile as the file will get closed when the destructor for my_stream is called at the end of scope.

Some additional minor points.  As discussed above in the comments, std::string should probably be used for Book::title, Book::author, and Book::publisher.  This is because std::string handles the case where the number of characters is unknown more gracefully without resorting to managing memory explicitly.  Likewise, collection would be better suited to a standard container (e.g., std::vector).  This does cause problems for the current implementation of indexBook, which could be changed to use the copy constructor of Book to store in collection.  For Book IO, operator>> and operator<< could be overloaded to replace and simplify code inside of readfile and printCollection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems and bad habits to be learning in this code.

```
using namespace std;
```

This is a dangerous practice, because it means all of the names declared in the `std` library namespace are imported into the global namespace which will cause you all kinds of weird problems in future.

If you want to avoid having to type `std::cout` and `std::string` all the time, you can instead write:

```
using std::string;
using std::cout;
```

Next:

```
typedef struct book { ... } Book
```

This is a C language construct that is completely unnecessary in C++.

```
struct Book {
};
```

it's that simple.

```
struct Book {
    char title[100];
};
```

Since you are aware of std::string, why not use it here?

```
using std::string;

struct Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string publisher;
    float price;
    int isbn;
    int pages;
    int copies;
};
```

The `indexBook` function is frankly scary.

```
void
indexBook(Book *my_book)
{
    memcpy(&collection[currentIndex], my_book, sizeof(Book));
    currentIndex++;
}
```

`memcpy` should be avoided in C++, you should instead rely on the copy/assignment/move operators built-in to C++ objects.

```
    collection[currentIndex] = *my_book;
```

If there is a particularly good reason why an object should not be copied, and the author of the object's class is any good, you will get a compiler error, whereas with `memcpy` you will just get undefined behavior.

Lets skip ahead a little:

```
void
printCollection(void)
{
    ...
}

void printCollection(void);
```

there's no harm here, but forward-declaring printCollection after it's definition is redundant.

```
Book *my_book = new Book;

indexBook(my_book);

...
delete my_book;
```

It's not clear here why you've done this. It seems wasteful. You could just as easily have done:

```
Book my_book;
```

But either way there is a simple problem: `my_book` has not been initialized. So what you copied into the collection is anyone's guess.

```
Book my_book {};
```

would default initialize it for you.

Now lets look at readfile.

```
fstream my_stream;
string line = " ";  // why?
my_stream.open("input.txt");
int i=0;
for (i = 0; ...)
{
   ...
}
my_stream.close();
```

You're doing a lot of unnecessary work and coding here. You're using C++ so objects have constructors, you can write `std::string line = " "` or `std::string line(" ")` or `std::string line {" "}` (preferred as of C++11). But you can also do the same for fstream. And lastly, unless you need `i` to be visible outside of the for loop, you can make it local to the loop.

Because `fstream` is an object, it also has a destructor, which will ensure the file is closed.

This all brings us down to

```
void
readfile()
{
    std::fstream my_stream("input.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; ++i)
    {
       std::string line {};  // default initialized.
       ...
    }
    // call to close is redundant
}
```

Now we're coming to the crux of what is actually broken with your code, most of which lies in this function.

1 You don't check that the file is open

2 You call `getline(my_stream, line)` in a while loop *inside* the `i` for loop,

3 You don't adjust `currentIndex`

4 (worst of all) you misuse `operator>>`.

In your code you write the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < currentIndex; ++i)  // *1
{
    while (getline(my_stream, line))  // *2
    {
        cin >> line >> collection[i].title;  // *3
```

Because you called `indexBook` on an uninitialized object in main, `currentIndex` is 1, so we will enter the for loop.

Now we try and read the first line of `my_stream` into `line` (*2) and if that succeeds, we enter the while loop body.

Now we try and read a word from `std::cin` *into line* followed by another word from `std::cin` into collection[0].title (*3, remember: i=0, and has to be `< currentIndex`).

You do no checking on these `std::cin` reads, if any of them fail it will just proceed through all of them doing nothing.

Finally we reach the end of the while loop and we again try `getline(my_stream, line)`. If this succeeds, we re-enter the while loop body.

*Note that `i` has not yet been changed, so the code still refers to `collection[0]`, overwriting any data that was fetched from `std::cin` in the first pass.

This will continue until we have exhausted `my_stream`, at which point we finally exit the while loop and reach the `for` loop.

`i` is incremented so that `i` now equals `1`. The condition is checked and it is no-longer true that `i < currentIndex` so we exit the for loop.

It appears you thought that you were writing code to read a word *from* line into `collection[i].title`. We can use `std::stof` and `std::stoi` to convert strings to `float` and `integer` so we might write something like this:

```
bool
readFile(void)  // returns true on success, false on error
{
    using std::getline;

    std::fstream my_stream("input.txt");
    if (!my_stream.is_open())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; ++i)
    {
        Book newBook {};   // temporary local to read into
        if (!getline(my_stream, newBook.title))
            break;
        if (!getline(my_stream, newBook.author))
            break;
        if (!getline(my_stream, newBook.publisher))
            break;
        std::string line;
        if (!getline(my_stream, line))
            break;
        newBook.price = std::stof(line);
        if (!getline(my_stream, line))
            break;
        newBook.isbn = std::stoi(line);
        if (!getline(my_stream, line))
            break;
        newBook.pages = std::stoi(line);
        if (!getline(my_stream, line))
            break;
        newBook.copies = std::stoi(line);

        collection[i] = newBook;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is certainly *far* from being idiomatic C++, but that's for your teacher/book to teach you. I will, however, skip ahead to how I would solve this assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string;

struct Book
{
    // suffix member variables with `_` to distinguish from function names
    // and parameters.
    string title_;
    string author_;
    string publisher_;
    float price_;
    int isbn_;
    int pages_;
    int copies_;

    // support `stream >> book` syntax with `operator >> ()`.
    // note that it's not a member of the class, so we declare
    // it as a `friend` function so it can have full access.
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, Book&);

    // because of the formatting, I wouldn't make this `operator <<`.
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "Title: " << "\t\t" << title_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "Author: " << "\t" << author_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "Publisher: " << "\t" << publisher_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "Price: " << "\t\t" << price_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "ISBN: " << "\t\t" << isbn_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "Pages: " << "\t\t" << pages_ << '\n';
        std::cout << "Copies: " << "\t" << copies_ << '\n';
    }
};

using Collection = std::vector<Book>;

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& str, Book& book)
{
    std::getline(str, book.title_);
    std::getline(str, book.author_);
    std::getline(str, book.publisher_);
    str >> book.price_ >> book.isbn_ >> book.pages_ >> book.copies_;
    str.ignore();
    return str;
}

bool
readFile(std::string filename, Collection& collection)
{
    std::fstream my_stream(filename);
    if (!my_stream.is_open())
        return false;

    Book newBook {};
    while (my_stream >> newBook)
        collection.emplace_back(std::move(newBook));

    return true;
}

void
printCollection(const Collection& collection)
{
    for (auto&& book : collection)  // or: const Book& book
    {
        book.print();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int
main()
{
    Collection collection;

    if (!readFile("input.txt", collection))
    {
        std::cerr << "readFile on input.txt failed\n";
        return 1;  // non-zero return from main indicates program failure
    }

    std::cout << "Read " << collection.size() << " books\n\n";

    printCollection(collection);
}
```